# Set agent label to any in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I can do this to use any node:

```
agent any
```

I can do this to hit a specific node:

```
agent { label "some-label-or-variable" }
```

Now how do I make this conditional? I want a variable I can set to be "any" or a specific label. Then I pass that variable to the "agent" of the stage and it uses "any" or a specific label. but label doesnt support "any". How do I do this?

Comment: Can you add a String parameter called 'NodeLabel' (just an example) to the job and then check to see if it is empty/null? Maybe something like:
if (!NodeLabel) { NodeLabel = "any" }. Then you can just use 'agent NodeLabel'

Comment: Maybe scripted pipelines, which provides more (programmatic) freedom?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it this way and it worked.

Approach one:

```
def labelValue = getLabelValue() ?: "" // set blank 

pipeline{
    agent {
       label labelValue
    }
}
```

Approach two:

Assuming you have something in Map config.

```
pipeline{
    agent {
       label config["label"]
    }
}
```

If key doesn't exist, it return null. Which means any.